# numpy matrix rank incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rank

I am having a strange problem using `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank()`.
I have a matrix A which has three columns and >100 rows. A consists of 0s and 1s. When I use `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank(A)` I got `answer=3`, which is correct.
But, when I add a new column with the same length to A (A now has four colunms), and use `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank(A)` I get `answer=1` which makes no sense. The numbers in the new column are in thousands. All data type is float32.

Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks!

Here is a randomly generated example. This is a 40*3 array A.

`array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]], dtype=float32)`

numpy.linalg.matrix_rank(A) is 3.

Now, I added the fourth column and A is now:

```
array([[  6.42096562e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  2.15370996e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  1.28050068e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  3.20350176e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  4.26681055e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  1.55057520e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.82897266e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  5.29479727e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  2.54858457e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.82017109e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  4.03392627e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  2.24184062e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.90389688e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  2.75718145e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.67467109e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  4.78061758e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  1.52730410e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.13073359e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  1.51932471e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.27319297e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  7.41743359e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  7.98595469e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  3.40574414e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  3.12823730e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  5.66580273e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  4.53152070e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.84440938e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  7.13604375e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  3.59290312e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  8.91415820e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  5.73751992e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  3.96208867e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  2.06492324e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  1.50155918e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.47758789e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.27601094e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  9.77911621e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  5.01128320e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  7.21259922e+04,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00],
   [  6.10147461e+03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
      1.00000000e+00]], dtype=float32)
```

numpy.linalg.matrix_rank(A) is 2. Could this be possible?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi... welcome to StackOverflow. When raising questions, you should ensure that the problem can be reproduced. You should include in your question the objective, current results, the error, and what you have tried so far. Please share the code and, if possible, the data or something to reproduce, as well as the the exact error you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your input with 3 columns and the column you want to add (at least the top 10 values)? as well as the max of the 4th column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"...which makes no sense."*  Actually, if you know how `matrix_rank` *estimates* the rank, it does make sense.  `matrix_rank` simply counts the number of [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of the matrix that are not approximately 0.  A singular value is considered 0 if it is small relative to the largest singular value.  When you add the fourth column containing numbers "in the thousands", you add a large singular value.  The three original singular values are small compared to the new large one, so they are considered 0 and are not counted towards the rank.

Here's an example.  `A` is an array of 0s and 1s.  `B` is created by appending a column containing 100000 to `A`:

```
In [217]: np.random.seed(123)

In [218]: A = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100, 3)).astype(np.float32)

In [219]: B = np.hstack((A, 100000*np.ones((A.shape[0], 1)))).astype(np.float32)
```

As expected, `A` has rank 3:

```
In [220]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
Out[220]: 3
```

Here are the singular values of `A`:

```
In [221]: np.linalg.svd(A)[1]
Out[221]: array([ 9.98757744,  5.41796255,  4.88814735], dtype=float32)
```

Like your example, `B` has rank 1:

```
In [222]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(B)
Out[222]: 1
```

We can see that `B` has one singular value that is much larger than the other three.  The difference in magnitude is enough that `matrix_rank` considers the smaller singular values to be approximately 0:

```
In [223]: np.linalg.svd(B)[1]
Out[223]: 
array([  1.00000000e+06,   5.45980692e+00,   4.90207911e+00,
         4.59457588e+00], dtype=float32)
```

Note that `matrix_rank` takes the data type into account.  If `B` is converted to 64 bit floating point, the rank computed by `matrix_rank` is 4:

```
In [226]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(B.astype(np.float64))
Out[226]: 4
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I have moved the example to the question.

Comment: this is a numerical thing. If SVD doesnt work well to estimate rank, then SVD is not the right approach. Other methods such as gaussian elimination should be checked out.